# Basic statistics help

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I know you guys are not allowed to give out any answers (I dont want any) I just need help in how to do it so I could practice on my own.

Say I was given mean and the S.D. of x and y ONLY and also i am given the correlation coeffecient $r$.

How would I find out the standard error of estimate for Y? I know the formula is $\sqrt{\frac{\sum{(y-y')^2}}{N}}$. and I am really confused on this.

and also I am to find if given x how would i predict her y?

Comment: What's $y'$? Do you mean $\bar{y}$ (`\$\bar{y}\$`)?

Comment: I have been using tutorteddy for long for my statistics problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you are given the expectation (mean) of a random variable, you may want to consider the following formula when calculating standard deviation:

$$ \sqrt{E[X^2] - E[X]^2} $$

Since we already have the expectation of X, we just need to find the expectation of $X^2$.

Also, recall the definition of correlation:

$$ corr(X, Y) = \frac{cov(X, Y)} {sd(X) * sd(Y)} = \frac{E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]} {sd(X) * sd(Y)} $$

We are only missing one piece to this formula...

With regards to predicting Y given X, we may think about a simple OLS linear regression without intercept.

$$ Y = \beta_1*X $$

Recall that $\beta_1$ can be calculated using the following formula:

$$ \beta_1 = \frac{cov(X, Y)} {var(X)} = corr(X, Y) * \frac{sd(Y)} {sd(X)}$$

If we can figure out $\beta_1$ and we are given an X value, we can predict Y.

Comment: Great answer! One small question: should $\beta_1=\frac{\sum XY}{\sum X^2}$ instead of $\frac{cov(X,Y)}{var(X)}$?

Comment: Your specification uses Summation Notation, which implies you are looking at the Sample Statistic rather than the Population Parameter. I can rewrite the definition for the $\beta_1$ coefficient assuming we are calculating a sample statistic: $$ \widehat{\beta_1} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x}) * (y_i - \bar{y})}} {\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}} $$

Note: Because we are calculating a Sample Statistic, we denote our estimator with a "hat" or "caret".

Comment: $$ \hat{\beta_1}=\mathop{argmin}_{\beta} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(\beta x_i-y_i)^2 \\ \Rightarrow \hat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$$ v.s. $$\min\limits_{\alpha,\beta_1} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (\alpha+\beta_1 x_i - y_i)^2 \\ \Rightarrow \hat{\beta_1}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2} \\ \hat{\alpha}=\bar{y}-\hat{\beta_1}\bar{x}$$ I don't think they lead to the same result when the intercept $\alpha$ is different.

Comment: The two specifications for $\beta_1$, $\sum{XY/X^2}$ and $cov(X,Y)/var(X)$ are indeed equal *if there is an intercept in the model*. If there is not they will not be equal; this is precisely why you can use $R^2$ only if there is an intercept.